# Very slow performance when using Npgsql Parameters

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

If I query my Postgres database with just a pure string, the query happens very quickly (~31 ms):

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(DatabaseConnStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    var command = conn.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select YoutubeID from Videos where YoutubeID='mmHX6dvXL8Y' limit 1;";

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader["YoutubeID"]);
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

However, if I use Npgsql parameters, like you're supposed to, the query is very slow (~11 seconds):

```
command.CommandText = "select YoutubeID from Videos where YoutubeID=@ytid limit 1;";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ytid", "mmHX6dvXL8Y");
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I would think these would complete in roughly the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npgsql: How do Prepared Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405116/npgsql-how-do-prepared-statements)

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info? What exactly does "very slow" mean, can you provide some numbers (e.g. with StopWatch)? Also, what version of Npgsql are you using?

Comment: The query without the Npgsql parameter runs in ~31ms, while the statements using Npgsql parameters takes ~11 seconds. I'm using Npgsql version 3.1.9.0. @Laurenz Albe, the "possible duplicate" question was from 6 years ago, and I'm using a MUCH later version. Can this really still be the case?

Comment: I don't know, it might be. I'd set `log_min_duration_statement` to 0 and run the slow and the fast query. Then look at the log and see what is there. Does it use parse/bind/execute or a simple statement? Is the duration on the PostgreSQL server also much different?

Comment: This seems to be an index usage issue. You'll have to log the statement and "explain" it in a query window.

Comment: This is fascinating...  can you please post the DDL?