# node-postgres parameterized query runs 10 times slower

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I was using [`node-posgres` parameterized queries](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query).

However, it was inserting data *very* slowly: 100 rows was taking 5 seconds!

Switching to [`pg-format`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format) and producing plain old SQL strings - even when executing them one at a time - reduced the time to insert 100 rows of the same data to 125 **ms**.

(If I then concatenate all 100 insert SQL strings and send it as a single query it goes down to just 25ms)

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405116/npgsql-how-do-prepared-statements)
(from Dec 13, 2010 mind you) that suggests a C# PostgreSQL client had serious problems with it.

Is `node-postgres` the same?

That is, should we not be using parameterized queries with `node-postgres`, or am I just doing something stupid?

- pg v8.11.1
- node v18.14

Thanks!

Here's the basic slow code if you're interested:

```
const insertSQL = `
    INSERT INTO "mytable"
    (  "column1", "column2", "column3",
        "column4", "column5", "column6",
        "column7", "column8", "column9"
    ) VALUES ( $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 );
`;

await pgClient.query("BEGIN");
for( let i=0; i<100; i+=1 ) {
    const test_data = test_datum[i];
    const values = [
            test_data.column1, test_data.column2, test_data.column3,
            test_data.column4, test_data.column5, test_data.column6,
            test_data.column7, test_data.column8, test_data.column9
        ];
    await pgClient.query(insertSQL, values);
}
await pgClient.query("COMMIT");
```

And the [`pg-format`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format) code that inserts 100 records
in 125**ms**:

```
await pgClient.query("BEGIN");
for( let i=0; i<100; i+=1 ) {
    const test_data = test_datum[i];
    const insertSql = pgformat(`
            INSERT INTO "mytable"
            (  "column1", "column2", "column3",
                "column4", "column5", "column6",
                "column7", "column8", "column9"
            ) VALUES (%L,  %L,  %L, %L,  %L,  %L, %L,  %L,  %L );
        `, test_data.column1, test_data.column2, test_data.column3,
            test_data.column4, test_data.column5, test_data.column6,
            test_data.column7, test_data.column8, test_data.column9 );
    await pgClient.query(insertSQL);
}
await pgClient.query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: Your so-called 125ms code wouldn't run at all due to a syntax error in the SQL - there's an errant comma after the last `%L`. Please be accurate when posting code.

Comment: What are the data types of `test_data.columnX` variables and the data types of the corresponding columns? As an aside, I would delete all quotes from your SQL as they are unnecessary code noise.

Comment: This is just sample SQL, to give you an idea.  Unfortunately I can't post the real code.

Comment: Some of the real column names require quotes, but agreed, I could have simplified the sample code further.
The (real) columns are mostly strings, a few numbers, and a few dates. 

I have code similar to this for about 10 different tables, and each of them are dramatically slower with the parameterized queries than with the SQL string formatted using pg-format.

Comment: The important point I'm trying to uncover is the parameter types should agree with the column types to avoid type conversion overhead. Although the performance hit you're experiencing does seem beyond what conversion would cause, it's worth eliminating that aspect.

Comment: Rather than working with a facsimile of "code you can't share", can you post an [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Also, please post full table schema so we know what you're dealing with.

Comment: You can certainly post real code which works but is different than your production code.  Just make sure it reproduces the behavior.